# Call-of-Duty Warzone: how do you get the FPS to show on screen?

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone

I checked the Blizzard launcher but didn't see it. I tried googling with no relevant results: "warzone how to show fps". I checked the ingame settings too.

How do you get the FPS to show on screen in Call of Duty: Warzone?

Answer (score 12):

In the game settings, go to:

Options » General » Telemetry

And enable: **Frames Per Second (FPS) Counter**

Answer (score 0):

I have options, No general. I guess they updated and removed it. so here is your answer: It does not exist and everything you google on will send you to the exact same bs.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Arqade.SE ^^ Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. Do you have something to support your claim? Like a screenshot or a reference to a patch mentioning the removal of the option? Also, seems like the OP is playing on PC, settings might vary with consoles, so are you also playing on PC?